# How to set invoice in parameter that print text to thermal printer in java swing

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer

i'm trying to set invoice in parameter print text in thermal printer but it show values are null. please help me anyone how to generate invoice in string parameter as a text.
 `

```
    PrinterService printerService = new PrinterService();

    System.out.println(printerService.getPrinters());

    //print some stuff. Change the printer name to your thermal printer name.

    printerService.printString("POSIFLEX PP6900 PRINTER", "   ****POS System**** \n"
            + "Date: "+Date+"     Time: "+Time+"\n"
            + "Receipt Number: "+ReceiptNumber+"\n"
            + "---------------------------------\n"
            + "Name          Qty    Rate     Amt\n"
            + "---------------------------------\n"
            + " "+ GetProductName(prodId)+ " "+quan+"  * "+totalamt+"  " +price+"\n"
            + "---------------------------------\n"
            + "Subtotal: "+GetCartAmount()+"\n"
            + "Tax: "+String.valueOf(tax)+"\n"
            + "Bonus: "+GetDiscountAmount(ReceiptNumber)+"\n"
            + "Payment: "+String.valueOf(total)+"\n"
            + "---------------------------------\n"
            + "------Served by: "+ItemSoldB+"-----\n"
    );
    // cut that paper!
    byte[] cutP = new byte[] { 0x1d, 'V', 1 };

    printerService.printBytes("POSIFLEX PP6900 PRINTER", cutP);`
```